# Unicode characters displaying weird in all browsers but Chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, browser, unicode

My unicode characters are displaying weird in all browsers but Chrome. [Here](http://sokiusvente2016.org/sventewip/home/)is my site- any idea why? I'm using the [Types](http://wp-types.com/home/types-manage-post-types-taxonomy-and-custom-fields/)plugin and just copy/pasting the uncode letters in.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for posting on StackOverflow. Try to create a custom wordpress page. Like so...

```
<?php 
include('/wp_blog_header.php'); //change this to reflect the location of your wp_blog_header.php
get_header();
echo "Your CharSet is: ".bloginfo('charset');
get_footer(); 
?>
```

This will tell you what wordpress has your Character Set setting set to. If it's not UTF-8 change it to reflect that (it's the most compatible with each language).

Alternatively, you can also add this line to your wp-config.php

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');   // force utf8
define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci'); // force collation
```

If I provided the best solution, please mark this as the answer to your issue :) Thanks again for posting.

Comment: It is UTF-8, it tells you that when you view source.

Comment: Unfortunately the link you provided above shows a forbidden error so there was no way for me to know this. Anytime I have seen this error the solution I have provided resolved it. If it doesnt its usually the plugin that is causing the error.

Comment: Could you try again? I'm allowing traffic.